# Trying to get access token for Paylocity Web API in Node.js but getting error "invalid_client"

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I have been trying to retreive the access token for the paylocity API. I am able to get it through postman with the client id and client secret however when I try and retrieve it with Node.js I get the message {"error":"invalid_client"}.

Here is my code

```js
 
 const apikey = {user name};
 const secret = {password};
 
 const url = "https://api.paylocity.com/IdentityServer/connect/token";
  const authorizationTokenInBase64 = Buffer.from(
    `${apiKey}:${secret}`
  ).toString("base64");


  const body = "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=WebLinkAPI";
 
  let config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${authorizationTokenInBase64}`,
      "Content-Type": `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,
    },
  };
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(url, body, config);
 
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error.response.data);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Digit

It meant your client id or client secret is wrong, please double those
And try to use `Content-Type: "application/json"` to see whether it works